# Unexpected inverse round at numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy

When an array is created using numpy it does something like an "inverse round". The input list is [0.7] and the numpy.array output is [0.69999999999999996]. Why is that happening?

```
>>> import numpy
>>> nparray = numpy.array([0.7])
>>> nparray[0]
// why is not 0.7 ?
0.69999999999999996
```

UPDATE:

Using dtype=numpy.dtype(decimal.Decimal) works but I don't understand why, any ideas? :

```
>>> import numpy,decimal
>>> nparray = numpy.array([0.7],dtype=numpy.dtype(decimal.Decimal))
>>> nparray[0]
0.7
```

Comment: This is not `numpy` related, try `"%.17f"%0.7` in the console. This is due to floating point numbers. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the way that binary floating-point numbers works:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations

*The decimal floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine.*

As the documentation explains, this is in the very nature of binary floating-point. The only way to avoid that is using another number notation.